# Phonegap, JQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin in IOS

Tags: jquery, phonegap, dropdown

Дорабатываю приложение на PhoneGap. Был список (SELECT), в котором отсутствовал фильтр списка значение.
Стандартным JS не смог сделать, поэтому решил использовать - "JQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin", версия  1.0.8.
В Андройде все правильно работает.
А в IOS, не раскрывается второй фильтрованный список. Показывает только первое значение и можно только его выбрать.
Как сделать чтобы фильтрованный список раскрывался скроллингом и можно было выбрать другое значение ?

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery_searchabledropdown_108.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   jQuery.browser = {};
   (function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
     jQuery.browser.msie = true;
     jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
   })();

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select-searchable").searchable();
   });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <select class="select-searchable">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>  
</body>
```

[image: Android]

[image: IOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта проблема проявлялась, когда список содержал всего одно значение.
Решил добавить нулевое значение с описанием "Все".

Таким образом в списке уже будет всегда больше одного значения, и проблема решена.